# Android runtime permissions and older apps

Tags: permissions

Since android 6 there are runtime permissions. Is this applicable to all apps? Or only apps that target the API of android 6 and higher?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, to all apps from android 6. Otherwise it would be a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

This applies only to apps targeting Android 6 or higher, which must be able to deal with them. Runtime permissions mean the app itself must request them from the user at runtime – which was not possible before (and thus no API available to do so). Hence older apps (and those targeting Android 5 or lower) cannot implement this.

For apps targeting Android 5 or older, the old permission model will be applied.